# Node on Windows 10 ENOENT 4058 with fs.rename

Tags: node.js, fs

So, I am trying to write a little script to rename files in a directory. System is Windows 10 with Node 12.13.1 
The renaming process should check for the file extension and then increment the file's prefix. I have most of the logic, if inelegantly hacked together, but I am struggling with solving this error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Projects\rename_app\2test.txt' -> 'C:\Projects\rename_app\1test.txt'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'rename',
  path: 'C:\\Projects\\rename_app\\2test.txt',
  dest: 'C:\\Projects\\rename_app\\1test.txt'
}
```

This error happens regardless of the order of the arguments supplied to the rename function, or whether the command is run with elevated privileges.

Here's a cleaned up version of the code with my console.logs removed:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Documents');
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        suffix = file.substring(file.length -3);
        if(suffix === "txt"){
            prefix = file.charAt(0);
            if(!isNaN(prefix)){
                newPre = prefix++;
                newFile = file.replace(newPre, prefix);
                file1 = path.join(__dirname, file);
                newFile1 = path.join(__dirname, newFile);
                fs.rename(file1, newFile1, function(err){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.log('it worked?');
                })

            }

        } 
    });
});
```

From searching around, I haven't come up with a solution, and I've tried to use the renameSync, as well as copying rather than renaming the files. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing `fs.readdir()` on this path:

```
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Documents');
```

But, then when you go to put the path back onto the results of `fs.readdir()`, you're only using `__dirname`.  You lost the `Documents` part of the path so you don't have the right path.

I'd suggest you change:

```
            file1 = path.join(__dirname, file);
            newFile1 = path.join(__dirname, newFile);
```

to this:

```
            file1 = path.join(directoryPath, file);
            newFile1 = path.join(directoryPath, newFile);
```